# Error when graphing with ggplot. geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use this code, it will create a graph just fine, but in rmarkdown it will show the error at the top. It shows the error with or without the `aes(group = 1)` in the main ggplot and/or the `geom_line()`. Any suggestions? None of the other posts I find about this question tell me what to do if the error persists after adding the `group = 1`.

```
ggplot(monthly_leads_dealer, mapping = aes(x = as.factor(month), y = n, group = 1))+geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group = 1))+
  geom_label(aes(label = n))+
  facet_wrap(~Dealer)+
  labs(title = "2021 Total Monthly Leads by Dealer", caption = "Source: Lead Sheet", x = "Month", y = "Totals")
```

[image]

EDIT: the warning will appear in and out of rmarkdown. Putting `warning = FALSE` in the markdown chunk header doesn't get rid of the warning in markdown.

EDIT: `error = FALSE` and `echo = FALSE` in the markdown code chunk didn't solve this particular issue, but `message = FALSE` did solve it.

Comment: This is not an error, just a warning, telling you that in some cases you only have one datapoint (which quite often arises from a falsely specified group aes)

Comment: @stefan How do i make it go away?

Comment: To add to @stefan ... The warning of ggplot helps you to debug or be confident about your data issues. If you would like to surpress the warning from your RMarkdown output, you can set `warning=FALSE` in your code chunk header (or set this as an knitr option applicable across the whole document).

Comment: @Ray Sorry i should clairify, the warning pops up when i run the code in and out of markdown. The ```warning=FALSE``` doesnt get rid of the warning.

Comment: Okay. Looks like it's not even a warning but simply a message. Hence, add `message=FALSE` to the code chunk.

Comment: +1 for stefan ... thanks for saving my day ... could not see the message because of the warning tunnel vision :)           Jacob, be aware that there is also a `error=FALSE` and obviously `echo=FALSE` for suppressing "messages".

Comment: @stefan ```message = FALSE``` worked! Thanks so much to both of you for the help! @Ray

Comment: also for posterity's sake, ```error = FALSE``` and ```echo = FALSE``` didnt solve this particular issue, but ```message = FALSE``` did solve it.